# Assigning to parent DataFrame affects child DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, copy

The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) and numerous SO answers clarify that assignment to a "child" DataFrame may or may not be reflected in the "parent" DataFrame (depending on some conditions).

What about the opposite situation: is it true that assigning to the "parent" DataFrame may or may not be reflected in the "child" DataFrame(s), and **it depends  on the exact same conditions**?

I noticed that `SettingWithCopy` warning doesn't seem to be raised when assigning to the "parent" DataFrame; nor is this discussed in the documentation.

```
df_parent = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2,2,3,3], 'b': range(4)})
df_child = df_parent[df_parent['a']==2]
df_child.loc[0,'a'] = 100 # `SettingWithCopy` warning
df_parent.loc[0, 'a'] = 1000 # no warning; but unclear if df_child is updated?
```

Comment: What is `df_child`?  You don't define it in your example.

Comment: @BrenBarn oops fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the documentation:

> All pandas data structures are value-mutable (the values they contain
>   can be altered) but not always size-mutable. The length of a Series
>   cannot be changed, but, for example, columns can be inserted into a
>   DataFrame. However, the vast majority of methods produce new objects
>   and leave the input data untouched. In general, though, we like to
>   favor immutability where sensible.

it "*works*" in both directions:

```
In [83]: df
Out[83]:
   a  b  c
0  0  9  5
1  9  1  5
2  7  0  0
3  3  6  9
4  4  0  8
5  4  5  8
6  1  3  6
7  4  4  9
8  6  7  4
9  2  9  6

In [84]: copy.ix[0,'a'] = 100

In [85]: copy
Out[85]:
     a  b  c
0  100  9  5
1    9  1  5
2    7  0  0
3    3  6  9
4    4  0  8
5    4  5  8
6    1  3  6
7    4  4  9
8    6  7  4
9    2  9  6

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
     a  b  c
0  100  9  5
1    9  1  5
2    7  0  0
3    3  6  9
4    4  0  8
5    4  5  8
6    1  3  6
7    4  4  9
8    6  7  4
9    2  9  6
```

use `.copy()` if you want an independent copy of your DF:

```
In [89]: df
Out[89]:
   a  b  c
0  3  4  2
1  9  5  1
2  1  9  0

In [90]: copy = df.copy()

In [91]: df.ix[0,'a'] = 100

In [92]: df
Out[92]:
     a  b  c
0  100  4  2
1    9  5  1
2    1  9  0

In [93]: copy
Out[93]:
   a  b  c
0  3  4  2
1  9  5  1
2  1  9  0
```

Comment: I guess no `SettingWithCopy` warning because the parent DF doesn't actually know which child DF are linked to it.